# Automated Deployment using CI server

Tags: c#, wpf, msbuild, teamcity, nant

In our project, deployment is always a pain, mostly because of the mistakes done by the release management team. Either they screw up the configuration or get the wrong version installed somehow. We use teamcity as our CI server, and it produces the artifacts as zip files(dll's and exe) which is usually passed on to the release team. My question is, is there a way to automate the whole deployment process?

Is there a commercial tool, which supports this?

We will want to do the following:

- Update the config files with environment specific values.
- Install windows services to the server.
- Upload the UI(WPF) bundle to the centralized location(which is pulled down by another application, sort of a launcher).
- Change the DB connection strings.

Do all the above for various environments(like int,uat and prod)

DB deployment since is a separate beast as such, need not be covered in this.

Any best practices, tools or solutions will be highly helpful.

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Please note that I'm not talking about web applications, but desktop application build using WPF.

Comment: Has anyone tried out OCTOPUS?

Comment: I have not used http://octopusdeploy.com/ however I have followed its progress and it certainly addresses the issues you listed above

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have used TeamCity for some fairly large projects and I have automated every aspect of deployments apart from the database. The main steps I use for each project are:

1. Get a TeamCity agent installed on the production server
2. Have the build get everything out of source control (you do have everything in source control right?).
3. Have a build step that builds and **publishes** your solution. This can be achieved by adding the following command line argument to your MSBuild call:

   /p:Configuration=[Your Config];DeployOnBuild=True;PackageAsSingleFile=False

   Your published files (and tranformed config files) will be written to the following directory:

   [Your Project Directory]\obj\[Your Config]\Package\PackageTmp
4. Using a scripting language (in my case Powershell) to copy the published artifacts to your deployment directory and make environment specific changes you mentioned. E.g. extracting archives, copying files, starting/stopping websites etc..
5. Run any automated testing (e.g. nUnit, Selenium etc...)

I find the best strategy is to have a .Net post-build event that invokes an appropriate powershell script passing in relevant details like the solution path and configuration name (alternatively, I have also had TeamCity pass the environment name to the Powershell script) so that it knows what it needs to do (e.g. Staging, Production etc...). You should find that a scripting language like Powershell can do **everything** that a person can do (and about 100x faster and 100% reliably).

There is so much content on Powershell out there that you can just google anything you need to do in Powershell and you will get an example. E.g. "powershell deploy WPF", "powershell upload FTP" etc...

In a previous job I needed to deploy windows services remotely and I found that with enough research, I was able to get the MSI for the service to uninstall the existing service and install the new one **completely silently** (i.e. no dialogs). This will help a lot in your quest for automation. I can elaborate on this if you would like.

Below is an example of a Powershell post build script I generally use:

*Note how I use some default parameter values so that I can execute the script directly from my Powershell editor to simulate and test different configurations on my local machine.*

```
param(
    [string]$configurationName="Debug",
    [string]$sourceDirectory="C:\SVN\<Your local solution location>")
Set-StrictMode -v latest
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop"

# Load required functions
$private:scriptFolder = & { (Split-Path $MyInvocation.ScriptName -Parent) }
. (Join-Path $scriptFolder DebugBuild.ps1)
. (Join-Path $scriptFolder StagingBuild.ps1)
. (Join-Path $scriptFolder ProductionBuild.ps1)
. (Join-Path $scriptFolder CommonBuildFunctions.ps1)

#Execute appropriate build
switch ($configurationName) {
    "Debug" { RunDebugBuild $sourceDirectory }
    "Staging" { RunStagingBuild $sourceDirectory }
    "Production" { RunReleaseBuild $sourceDirectory }
}
```

*To execute a publish on development machines, I setup a VS publish profile for the solution that is committed to SVN so the other developers can use it. This profile publishes directly to the local deployment directory.*

Comment: Great answer!  Thanks for taking the time to map it out ;--)  Awesome

Comment: what is it RunDebugBuild  function ?

Comment: You said to put a build agent on the production server, but how do you guarantee that agent will be the one that runs the build?

Comment: @lorddev I haven't used TeamCity for a while now, but I would imagine there are ways you can configure TeamCity to use specific agents for specific builds.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it out using the Agent Requirements section of the build configuration.

Answer (score 3):

We use TeamCity for our deployments in addition to CI and it works really well. Here are a couple things that may help:

- If you're using VS2010, check out the [SlowCheetah plugin](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5). It can do the config file transforms to do what you need to replace DB connection strings and other environmental-sensitive variables. These transforms happen automatically when you build based on the selected build configuration.
- Check out [MSDeploy](http://www.iis.net/download/webdeploy). While it gets most of it's attention for deploying web applications, it can do a lot of other things, like installing windows services and syncing files to a destination directory. While most people install it as an IIS add-in, it can be installed as a separate service that has no dependencies on IIS.

If you're not using VS2010 (or don't want to use SlowCheetah), here's how we you could handle the config settings:

- Create an app config for each different environment (I'm assuming you
  have a build configuration set up for each environment). Add the
  configuration name to the end of the config file, so in Prod we have
  App.config.Prod and QA we have App.config.QA.
- Put your complete configuration for each environment in it's respective config file for
  that environment.
- As part of your build (we use the "BeforeBuild" target in the project file), use msbuild to copy the environmentally specific app.config over the actual one. Here's a custom msbuild target we use to do this:

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
      <EnvironmentAppConfig>App.config.$(Configuration)</EnvironmentAppConfig>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="ReplaceAppConfig">
      <Message    Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)$(EnvironmentAppConfig)')" 
                  Text="Copying $(EnvironmentAppConfig) -> App.config" Importance="high" />

      <Message    Condition="!Exists('$(ProjectDir)$(EnvironmentAppConfig)')"
                  Text="No $(EnvironmentAppConfig) found. Leaving App.config as is." Importance="high" />

      <Copy   SourceFiles="$(ProjectDir)$(EnvironmentAppConfig)"
              DestinationFiles="$(ProjectDir)App.config"
              Condition="Exists('$(ProjectDir)$(EnvironmentAppConfig)')" />

  </Target>
  ```

Let me know if you need any other details.

Comment: I try to avoid full copies of the App.config for each environment. There is a lot of redundancy. Ideally (and it is obviously more work) it would be better to just store the differences and apply them using something like XPath to the original app.config. Like what .Net 4 now does with their config transformation files.

Answer (score 1):

Teamcity + Octopus deploy

Octopus for windows service automated deploys

Answer (score 0):

Our release team uses Anthill Pro - this also has ability to do CI, but they just use it to deploy packages (in our case mostly web site code).
The cool thing about Anthill is the whole client(agent)-server setup, so it traverses firewalls, NAT etc with some effort. And it has approval and scheduling workflow.

As far as configs, this is a different beast - unfortunately both devs and release team have to change these, and somehow merge the result. Consider that you want to add new config key, but release team has to add production settings for DB connection. The trick is that devs are not supposed to know production DB connection string.
So this is not automated (in our case anyways).

Answer (score 0):

I'm partial to TeamCity, which is a Jetbrains product, the company that makes the essential ReSharper (no, I don't work for them, drat the luck). TeamCity, at least last time I checked, is a free product for up to 20 users and 20 build configurations. It has some nice auto-build and blame features. Excellent, really.

Answer (score 0):

You mention a Commercial tool...

TFS, or specifically Team Build, completely supports building the code and deploying it.  Whenever we build a web app, it auto deploys to our Dev and QA servers.  After deployment we have it run through a suite of web tests to ensure everything is functional.  Then the real fun begins with our QA team ;)

Although we don't auto deploy to production, we could certainly do that as well.